# Is it possible to extend gVim's SignColumn into empty lines?

Tags: vim

For purely aesthetics reasons I want to extend the signcolumn all the way to the end of the file without making new lines. Is it possible?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you want is not possible.

Like line numbers and fold indicators, signs are placed on *lines*. There is no line, there, therefore there can be no sign, therefore there can be no sign column.